# Not able to update state with editorState from server in ReactJs for draftJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, draftjs

I have implemented a rich text editor to React with the support of draftJs.

I am sending the editorState data to the server after converting to raw data and stringify it. That works well for rendering it to the front end.

Now, I want to take this data and update the editorState with this data. So, the user can edit the text with available data.

I don't, why it doesn't work. Please help me. I am not getting what should I do.

My code:
Importing dependencies

```
import { Editor } from "react-draft-wysiwyg";
import { EditorState, ContentState, convertFromRaw, convertToRaw } from "draft-js";
import "react-draft-wysiwyg/dist/react-draft-wysiwyg.css";
```

Initial State:

```
const [editorState, setEditorState] = useState(() =>
    EditorState.createEmpty()
  );
```

Trying to edit:

```
      setEvent(current);
      const data = JSON.parse(current.description);
      // EditorState.createWithContent(convertFromRaw(data));
      setEditorState(EditorState.createWithContent(ContentState.createFromText('Hello world')));

     // EditorState.createWithContent(convertFromRaw(JSON.parse(current.description)));

      // convertToRaw(JSON.parse(editorState.getCurrentContent()));
      // const state = current.description;

      // As per draft.js docs, I didn't understand the syntax
      // convertFromRaw(rawState: state): ContentState

      // EditorState.createWithContent(JSON.parse(current.description));
      
      // setEditorState(JSON.parse(current.description));
```

Tried all this stuff. But, nothing updates the `editorState` to `current.description`.
Note: `current.description` is a JSON string that contains raw object data.

Resources:
[createwithcontent](https://draftjs.org/docs/api-reference-editor-state/#createwithcontent)

[reactrocket persisting state](https://reactrocket.com/post/draft-js-persisting-content/)

Comment: Please add your suggestion for editing the title of this question. If you think this is not appropriate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved the issue. Official DraftJs docs were a little confusing.
It should have some examples. So, beginner and intermediate developers can get it.

I have done this:

```
setEditorState(EditorState.createWithContent(convertFromRaw(JSON.parse(current.description))));
```

I hope my effort would be helpful to others, and they don't need to waste their time like me.